# Apache and ZeroConf

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, bonjour, mdns

I have a machine running Ubuntu on which I've installed Apache (v2).

What I'm trying to do is enable ZeroConf so that the Apache server will broadcast itself over the network and then will be able to be picked up using Bonjour on OS X systems.

It seems that Apache unfortunately has no support for ZeroConf out-of-the-box so some additional module will be needed.

There are a number of different libraries out there compatible with various versions of Apache and operating systems but mostly fairly out-of-date (mod_zeroconf, mod_rendezvous, mod_bonjour, libapache2-mod-dnssd, amongst others)

Has anyone had any experience with these different libraries and can they recommend a fairly current one that is compatible with Apache2 on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to be answering my questions a lot on here these days, but after a day of trying things out I **finally** managed to get it to work by installing mod_dnssd and figuring the rest out myself (although I found the documentation to be really, really bad).

Here's what I did:-

**1. Install mod_dnssd**

`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-dnssd`

**2. Import the module into Apache and enable the library:**

Open your Apache config file (mine is in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and add the following lines at the top:-

`LoadModule dnssd_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dnssd.so`

`DNSSDEnable on`

**3. Restart Apache with the new settings**

`/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Your web server will now be broadcasted using ZeroConf/Bonjour. You can verify this on your Mac by running `dns-sd -B _http._tcp .` and your machine running the web server should be listed.

For information, see: http://jona.than.biz/blog/?p=17

Comment: Only just saw this question, sorry! :-P Personally I'd just add an entry to the list of Avahi services if the alternative was spending an hour fiddling with Apache, not my idea of a good time.